# SVN: log of the update operations in the working copy

Tags: svn, revert, working-copy

I just have updated the live working copy of the our repo, and I want to revert this change. The problem is that I don't know what was the working revision before the update, and there were so many changes to the repo, that I'm having a hard time to figure out where I should revert.

Is there a log of the operations done to the working copy of the repo?

Comment: As far as I know: no

This is no solution but a widely accepted best practice: When you need a not-so-easily to be changed checkout, use a tag